# ERROR ITMS-90207 Invalid bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I’m having issue when uploading to app store an app with this framework.

> *ERROR ITMS-90207 "Invalid bundle.  The bundle at .../TesseractOCR.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.*

In my Xcodeproj i have another project inside, i'm including the framework on dependencies, linked libraries and Copy Files.

Do you know something about this issue?.

**Many Thanks**, Nahuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing Mach-O Type to Dynamic Library in Build Settings.
Xcode wasn't generating an executable.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. I fixed the issue by following this process:

> In your `info.plist` file, under the key **Executable file**, add the value `$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting Bitcode off. (below two are related settings)

1. Build Settings > Build Options > Enable Bitcode : NO
2. Uncheck "Include Bitcode" when uploading app to Itunes Connect (after archiving)

Comment: This worked for me too, but comes at the cost of your app not being optimized for the target device...

Comment: This is not working for me. Could you please suggest any other setting that I might be missing. Thanks